# Meteor js - client view doesnt update (AWS Lightsail + Nginx reverse proxy)

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, websocket, amazon-lightsail

My Meteor app doesnt want to work properly when uploaded to AWS Lightsail.

The problem is - when I update a document in collection the changes are not reflected on the client, and even more strange - the updated variable disappears from the client view.
Everything works well in development on my local machine though. I also had the same app deployed to my office server machine and was running without any issues.

I created simple script to reproduce the problem, see on the vid: https://streamable.com/mnu26j

So adding or removing document reflects without issue on the client side, but when I try to edit a variable (name) - it saves it to the database, but the client doesnt the reflect the change until I refresh the page.

To me it feels like there might be some problem with maybe wrongly configured websocket connection that doesnt work together with AWS services, but I might be totally wrong on that. In the full version of the app the websocket was constantly reconnecting and closing connection when I tried to authenticate the user (in a cycle of few hundred times per minute) and the app was stuck on log in screen.

Maybe someone has already met a similar problem or at least would have some clue where I could look for a cause of it?

Let me know if you want me to provide any more details.

Comment: Can you please add the publication and subcription code (in case you use pub/sub). If you get the data diferrently please show that code.

Comment: It sounds like a publication issue. Code please